# android - buttons above ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I've been stuck on this for a while so I thought I would ask.  Previously I had an ImageView with buttons underneath.  But I would like to have the buttons on top, and the ImageView underneath the buttons, but can't figure out how to do it.  Here is the XML I have at the moment.  Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_ILLNESS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button_ILLNESS"
            android:text="@string/illness"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_SYMPTOM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_ILLNESS"
            android:text="@string/symptom"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_REMEDY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_SYMPTOM"
            android:text="@string/remedy"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_HELP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_REMEDY"
            android:text="@string/help"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_INFO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_button_height"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_HELP"
            android:text="@string/info"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_android_650x480" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so how about setting LinearLayout background to this particular drawable image?

Comment: @bhuos - Sweet, that did the trick.  Thanks!  You should put your suggestion as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you buttons on top:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_ILLNESS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button_ILLNESS"
            android:text="@string/illness"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_SYMPTOM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_ILLNESS"
            android:text="@string/symptom"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_REMEDY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_SYMPTOM"
            android:text="@string/remedy"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_HELP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_REMEDY"
            android:text="@string/help"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_INFO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button_HELP"
            android:text="@string/info"
            android:textSize="@dimen/menu_button_text_size" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, i would suggest using nested `LinearLayout`'s, internal - horisontal for buttons and vertical for layout with buttons and image.

Comment: User `CTRL+SHIFT+F` or `CTRL+I` for Indent and formatting